# Prevent display math from creating a new line at the start of an item?

Tags: math-mode, lists, description

```
\begin{description}
\item[xyz] \[x=y\]
\end{description}
```

`x=y` appears on the line below `xyz`, if I changed `\[x=y\]` to some normal text it wouldn't create the new line.  How can I stop it?

Comment: Is `\line` similar to `\item`? And, do you want `x=y` to be horizontally centred just like `\[x=y\]`?

Comment: By default, you are entering display mode by using `\[\]`. Hence, it will automatically create a new line for you in math mode. If you want to use inline math, simply use `$<content>$`

Comment: @Werner Sorry I meant item, and no, I want x=y to appear on the same line as xyz does, with the math example it goes to a new line.  Azetina I don't want inline math

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[xyz]$x=y$
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

Based on the given comment.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\newcommand\myitem[2]{\item[$#1$]\hfill$#2$\hfill\null}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\myitem{xyz}{\frac10+0^0}
\myitem{\frac10}{0^0}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### For those who dislike `\everymath`

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\newcommand\myitem[2]{\item[$\displaystyle#1$]\hfill$\displaystyle#2$\hfill\null}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\myitem{xyz}{\frac10+0^0}
\myitem{\frac10}{0^0}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there not a better way other than to just type that every time?

Comment: @STRAIGHTOUTTACOMPTON: What do you want to automate?

Comment: I want it centered, I want display math, but I don't want to have to do a special case of changing how I do math mode everytime I want to do it at the start of an item.

Comment: @STRAIGHTOUTTACOMPTON: If there is some form of consistency in your usage, then automation is easy. For example, if you always have `\item[..] \[...\]`, then you can write a macro `\myitem` that formats things the way you want. If not, then it's more difficult.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't rely on `\everymath` here, it is considered quite problematic in LaTeX.

Comment: I'd consider `\everymath{\displaystyle}` wrong under all respects.